# Viewing automated cost matrix for DHD in TraMineR

Tags: r, sequence-analysis, traminer

I'm using social sequence analysis, and comparing between different distance methods for my data. I'm wondering if there is a way to view/call the automatic substitution cost matrix that the dynamic hamming distance procedure uses?
I have been able to create what I think would be the substitution cost matrices with the seqcost and the seqsubm functions (code below). Both these functions give me the same results - which is to be expected. However, I am wanting to know that what I've generated using this code is what the alogorthim would be using to compute? And, is there a way to view the substitution cost matrix that the procedure uses?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

````
#Compute the Dynamic Hamming distances. 

dist.dhd <- seqdist(number.seq, method = "DHD", with.miss = FALSE, norm = "none")
dist.dhd

##create DHD cost matrix - both functions give same output

dhdcost <- seqcost(number.seq, method = "TRATE", time.varying = TRUE, transition = "both")
dhdcost


couts <- seqsubm(number.seq, method = "TRATE", time.varying = TRUE, transition = "both")
round(couts, 2)
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help page of function `seqdist` states:

> When sm = NULL, the substitution-cost matrix is automatically created
> for "HAM" with a single substitution cost of 1 and for "DHD" with the
> costs derived from the transition rates at the successive positions,
> i.e. with sm = "TRATE".

Function `seqcost` returns both the substitution costs and the indel costs. Function `seqsubm`is an alias of `seqcost` that returns only the substitution costs. So we get of course the same substitution costs with these two functions. DHD uses only substitution costs and, therefore, we can use `seqsubm`.

Function `seqdist` computes the substitution costs for DHD by calling `seqsubm` with arguments `method='TRATE'` and `time.varying=TRUE`. For `transition` it uses the default `transition='both'`. So what you have computed should be what `seqdist` uses by default when `sm=NULL`.

In all cases, if you have any doubts, we strongly suggest to compute the costs with `seqcost` (or `seqsubm`) and then provide the substitution costs as `sm` argument (and, when applicable, the indel cost(s) as `indel` argument) to `seqdist`.

Comment: Thank you very much Gilbert - this was very helpful.